# Get details about background process, started from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, background-process

I have a bash script which starts some processes in background, but when I do

`ps aux | grep main_script.sh`

ps shows more processes than I expect, so I'd like to further investigate/analyze what are those processes (sample output):

```
user 10001  ...  /bin/bash main_script.sh
user 10002  ...  /bin/bash main_script.sh
user 10003  ...  /bin/bash main_script.sh
```

So, since all those pids are pointing to the parent script that started them as the command that's being ran (last part of ps output), I wonder if there is a way to take any of those process ids listed by ps, and get the info about what is actual command ran in the background, e.g.

if the main_script.sh contains this code:

```
./path/to/my/other/script.sh &
other_script_pid=$!
echo $other_script_pid
```

Which prints 10002, for example.

Is there any way I can get **./path/to/my/other/script.sh &** given the pid **10002** , rather than its parent script **main_script.sh**?

Thanks in advice, any feedback if highly appreciated! :)

Comment: What does `main_script.sh` _do_? If `main_script` only starts one other executable, the best approach is to make it `exec` that executable so its process table entry is replaced instead of adding a child at all. That is to say, use `exec` at the right place and the thing your script starts will take over the script's PID of 10001 instead of getting a new PID 10002.

Comment: (btw, executables shouldn't have extensions; and giving a _bash_ script an _sh_ extension is particularly problematic -- bash and sh are two different shells; see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm fairly familiar with differences between sh and bash, I'm bash developer :)
Since in unix everything is a file, extension serves more like a convention rather than the function, meaning if you specify #!/bin/bash at the top of the script, or run your script with bash explicitly, it absolutely doesn't matter how you call the script, or which extension it has.. Btw, names are not real anyway, they are just meant to give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.. Btw, as I stated, it run a multiple processes, not only bash scripts, so exec is not an option :/

Comment: Yes, it's a human-communication problem, not a technical problem, but that doesn't mean it's not a problem. The essay goes into that, in detail; telling me things it says is telling me you didn't read it. (It also tells me you aren't a longtime #bash IRC member; it's been part of the factoid database there for a long time)

Comment: Getting back to the question you asked... my usual preferred way to track sub-subprocesses is by passing a unique file handle through, and then using `fuser`-esque tools to look up which processes have that file open.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem even without inspecting processes, but I really appreciate your help! Btw, I just checked and accepted answer really does the trick, in case you ever need it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sub-process isn't a daemon then the sub-process' parent process id should be the pid of your script.  `ps --ppid 10002` (with suitable flags to get the info of interest).  They should also share the same session ID `ps -s ...`

Comment: Oh, thanks a tone, that's exactly what I was looking for!! :)
Turned up I managed to solve the "unwanted processes" problem just after posting the question (by modifying the code even without inspecting processes), but this will certainly come handy the next time I need to investigate!
Thanks again, I really appreciate it! :)